# Manga where a dragon dies and reincarnates as a human villager

Tags: story-identification, manga, dragons, reincarnation

The manga is like a dragon dies and reincarnates or is reborn as a human who is a villager, which has some or all of his dragon powers. I don't remember much of what happened in it, but I know that its first encounter as villager was a lamia (snake-like women). Other than that, I don't remember much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[Good Bye, Dragon Life](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/goodbye-dragon-life)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> After living a long life as the strongest and oldest dragon, he is slain by a human hero. He awakes to find himself reborn as a human, Dolan, in a remote village. He works hard as a farmer and sometimes hunts for food. His life is simple in this small village, but he is surrounded by love. He soon finds happiness he'd never experienced in his life as a dragon. However, dangerous monsters are lurking around his village lately and he goes to the woods to investigate when he finds out an army of monsters are heading his way...

The protagonist was a dragon who died and was reincarnated as a human villager. In the second chapter of the manga, he encounters a lamia while wandering alone in a forest.

[image]

[image]